# Tutorial mode in Civ Beyond Earth

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civ V, there was a tutorial mode that would teach you the basics of the game. Is there a similar thing in BE? The closest thing I see is the quests, which is kind of a tutorial, but I just won my first game and learned very little from it.

Comment: You could try raising the advisor help to maximum to see if that teaches you more.

Comment: I found `ADVISR` extremely useful in learning the basics.  When you start up a new game it should come up, and you should choose "New to Civ".  You can also choose that you want all of the tutorial information (I forget the exact text on that button).  He'll pop up periodically with useful information, and give you little screenshot slideshows in certain spots to show you how specific mechanics function (Like the tech web, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a dedicated "tutorial mode" in BE.

However, as @nzifnab mentioned in his/her comment, the `ADVISR` system is pretty much a tutorial. In general, it seems the advisors have been re-vamped a bit. They seem much more useful this time around, and also provide continual help for reoccurring situations.

For instance, in my current game, I get a pop-up every time one of my covert agents is idle, so I know to open the covert ops menu and give them a new assignment. (While I am personally starting to find it a bit annoying, I can certainly see the benefit for newer players.)

If you feel a little lost, I suggest increasing the `ADVISR` setting in the gameplay menu.